# Access deep zoom images stored on AWS S3 from JS

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, openseadragon

We are trying to serve large deep zoom images from our private S3 bucket and view them in a browser with an appropriate deep zoom image viewer. The viewer (OpenSeadragon) makes HTTP requests for parts of the image when necessary (the image is so large that it is divided up into thousands of small jpgs, each stored in a specific file structure based on level and position).

I'm using the SDK for JavaScript in the browser, and I've created a Cognito Identity Pool and associated policy per the instructions in the AWS guide. I'm able to set the credentials in the AWS.config object. Once the credentials are set, I generate a presigned URL to supply OpenSeadragon with the location of the deep zoom image:

```
const params = {
                    Bucket: <my-bucket>,
                    Key: '<sensitive-data>/<sensitive-data>.dzi'
                };
me.dzi_url = me.s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
```

OpenSeadragon makes a request for the key I specify in the params, and it returns the file correctly. However, OpenSeadragon makes subsequent requests for the individual jpg files needed to view different parts of the image as needed. Their API is smart and retains the AWS signature and appends it to each request, but the file name is different for each jpg based on its location within the file structure. The Key param would look like this if I were to generate another presigned URL for it:

`Key: <sensitive-data>/<sensitive-data>_files/<level>/<x_position>/<y_position>.jpg`

Naturally, I get a 403 (forbidden) error for every GET request subsequent to the first.

My question is this: without making our S3 bucket content public, what is the best way to access the content via the REST API from client-side JavaScript, given that I can only specify the location of the .dzi file when generating the presigned URL? Is this a situation in which we'd need to use CloudFront's presigned cookies to request multiple files at a time (like HLS streaming video)?

Note: I've already modified OpenSeadragon's source code to generate presigned URLs for every jpg request it makes, but that approach still resulted in the 403 errors.

Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: Once a user authenticates with Cognito, are you okay for them to access _every_ tile graphic? If so, you could assign an IAM Role to the authenticated Cognito user that has access to the objects in S3, without having to use pre-signed URLs.

Comment: We haven't actually implemented any auth in our application yet, so I gave full S3 access permission to the unauthorized Cognito role associated with the identity pool. The HTTP requests to the bucket still result in the 403 error. I have another role that I created to access the bucket - should I assume that role instead?

Comment: Are you saying that the client app assumes the **Unauthenticated role**, and that role has been granted access to the images in S3, but accessing the objects still results in a 403 error? If so, I would recommend that you check the policy and also check that the code is actually assuming that role. It should work, you've just got to find out where it isn't doing something right.

Comment: I think the code is assuming the role correctly, because once I set the credentials using

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: <my-identitypool-id>
});
```
I'm able to see the accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, and sessionToken in AWS.config.credentials. 

Also, the bucket has all public access turned off, and no bucket policy has been applied. Is the missing link that I should be applying a bucket policy and removing the two options to block public access through access point policies?

Comment: You should _not_ use a bucket policy. If the app is using those assumed credentials, and the "unauthenticated" IAM Role has permission to access S3, then it should be working.

Comment: I ended up modifying OpenSeadragon's URL generation function to use the SDK's presigned URLs. S3's getObject function works just fine once the code assumes the unauthenticated IAM role that has S3 permission, but the HTTP requests fail without presigned URLs. I can't use getObject to correctly view the images with OpenSeadragon, so this seemed like the best solution.